# Android Wearable Passing DataMap in AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, wear-os

I am developing an app where communication needs to occur constantly between a wearable running Android Wear and the phone. The basic progression of events involving communication between the two are as follows:

1. Phone sends wearable a piece of data in a DataMap and waits for a DataLayerListener event.
2. Wearable waits to receive data and responds with a piece of data in a DataMap after a calculation and then waits for another DataLayerListener event.
3. Phone receives data from wearable and after some calculation repeats 1-3.

My question is would it be best to perform this with an AsyncTask so that the UI thread doesn't hang waiting for the responses? And if this is the best solution, should I create a new GoogleApiClient each time I run the task or do it once in onPreExecute() or try to get the client from the MainActivity?

Comment: I don't think AsyncTask would be the best solution here. Rather you should implement a service which would accept data and send data to and from wearable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Paresh said, in my opinion a Service is much better, because it can be running until you want, and it is no necessary to create a new GoogleApiClient every time that you create the AsyncTask, just needs to have one.

Regarding the second question, what I do in my app is: create the Service and when onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId), create the GoogleApiClient. When the client is connected, the corresponding listeners are added to it.

An example of this last part:

```
@Override //ConnectionCallbacks
public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
    Log.d(TAG, "Google API Client connected");

    Wearable.DataApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);
    Wearable.MessageApi.addListener(mGoogleApiClient, this);

    startDataExchange();
}
```